# Are notifications possible with plain HTML, CSS, JS?

Tags: javascript, rest, notifications, chat

I am making a web chat application. The app is mostly designed to be viewed from mobile devices, but is also accessible from a standard PC. The back-end is Kinvey mBaas and my chats are stored in Kinvey collection (3 fields: firstUser, secondUser and history). The communication happens via REST API and all my data is stored in JSON strings.

Can I get some sort of "notifications" when I get new message from other user?

Thanks!

**Disclaimer:** I have read 5-6 different topics, tutorials and articles about notifications, I even tried the PubNub guide/tutorial, but I did want to use any 3rd party APIs. This is a school project and I'm still learning, plus time is ticking and I am in a kind of hurry. So I ask you guys.

Comment: html/css have nothing directly to do with notifications. they're for formatting/display of information.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not sure whether you're asking about the "client-side" or "server-side" notifications, I'll mention both:

#### Browser's visual notifications

You can try using [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). MDN contains a pretty [simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Example) of this API in use.

It has a pretty decent support from the major web browsers (even the latest Edge supports it): http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications

#### Server to Client "notifications"

Since you've mentioned using REST API (provided by Kinvey that I've never heard before, but I assume they do not provide a way to implement your own communication channels like with WebSockets or Web Push API), probably the simplest (but not very efficient) way to check for new messages would be to periodically send a request to your REST API and just ask for new messages.

You can achieve this by using [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

A better solution would be to use WebSockets (eg. using Socket.io) to establish a persistent TCP channel between a client and the server. Then, your server could "push" new messages directly to any listening clients, without them being required to manually check if there is something new waiting in the queue).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give Notification API a try. Manually asking for messages seems too brutal, even for my very, very un-optimised app. Am I correct? I mean, sending request every 10 secs, seems a lot

Comment: @Alex Since this is just a "school project", the only thing you should worry about are limits on your REST API (if any). But yes, in general, it's not a good idea to use pooling to fetch this kind of data. As I've mentioned, even a simple WebSockets channel would be a much better solution (and it's fairly simple to implement actually).